Outlook data file cannot be accessed after migration to new computer
I am transferring all my files from a Windows 10 PC to a new Windows 11 PC and am having issues moving my Outlook .PST files for POP accounts.
On Windows 10, the Outlook version is:
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20160) 32-bit
and the Outlook Files folder is in "This PC > Documents > Outlook Files" i.e.
C:\Users(my account)\Documents\Outlook Files
which is not mapped to OneDrive.
On the target Windows 11 computer, I have installed "classic" Outlook having version:
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2410 Build 16.0.18129.20030) 64-bit
Steps I took so far:

Created POP account in the target Outlook and verified the connection. This created a new .PST file in "OneDrive > (user name) > Documents > Outlook Files"; I don't think I want my outlook mapped to OneDrive, so...
Closed Outlook on the "old" computer and copied the corresponding .PST file to the new computer in a local folder not mapped to OneDrive.
Closed Outlook (new computer), deleted the newly created .PST file and launched Outlook.
When Outlook prompted for the .PST file location, I directed it to the copied file.

Outlook seems to have no problem reading the file (I can see all my old folders and messages) but when I try to send a new message from the POP account or sync accounts to get new messages, the sync reports a send/receive error 'Outlook data file cannot be accessed'.
I tried using the repair process (SCANPST.EXE) which appeared to detect issues but also appeared to complete a successful repair, but the issue persists.
My objective is to transfer all the emails from my old to new computer for my POP accounts and I don't think I want to switch to IMAP. What procedure should I follow, since the steps I tried so far don't seem to be working.
Addendum:
This may be turning into a new question. I have found that my PST file will work if I place it in the same folder as Outlook placed the new file (step 1 above) i.e. on OneDrive, but can't access a PST file placed in a local folder. Why would Outlook allow me to relocate the PST file to an arbitrary location but be unable to access it there?

You can disable Documents being contained within OneDrive by disabling the synchronization of Documents within the Settings within OneDrive. I can’t tell if you created an account that can send emails then simply added your additional PST files. That’s most certainly what I have done in the past when dealing with Outlook.

@Ramhound I guess I could exclude my Outlook Files from OneDrive sync, but I wanted to keep the focus on why I can't send or receive emails for an account which works fine on the "old" computer, but doesn't on the new one after the steps I described. Is there an incompatibility in PST files between the versions of Outlook? Do  I need to perform the desired migration following a different procedure?

“ Is there an incompatibility in PST files between the versions of Outlook?” - No; Besides your essentially using the same version. If you were using Outlook 2010 and Office 365 (2410) there might be a possibility but your using a build that’s a month apart so that absolutely is not possible

@Ramhound per my addendum, it looks like Outlook is OK with a PST under OneDrive and a folder acceptable to Outlook can't be excluded from OneDrive sync. Looks like Microsoft is forcing me to keep my PST under OneDrive, unless there is some detail I am overlooking.

It’s absolutely optional. OneDrive synchronization of Documents is a separate issue of importing a PST within Outlook. I would create a new account and locate its respective PST files then manually copy the existing PST file to that location and import it as an existing file.

@Ramhound Solved my problem. It had to do with the method for moving PST files, as I wrote up in my own answer.

In my experience, backing up .pst files in OneDrive is not recommended because .pst files take up a lot of space, and the backed up .pst files can also get corrupted in the cloud.
When you want to replicate a copy on the cloud, manually copy the PST in the OneDrive folder. This will result in one copy in the folder in OneDrive being used for backup purposes, and another copy in your Outlook client that can be kept open by Outlook.
You can refer to the discussion in this thread:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165970/outlook-pst-files-will-not-syncronizie-on-onedrive


My problem came from relocating the PST files via an incorrect procedure. Your link clued me in to the answer which I wrote up.

I successfully moved my Outlook PST files onto my new computer. The issue I got caught on relates to the required steps in Outlook to switch files.
Steps I followed for successful move are as follows (assumes we already know the location of the PST files on the old computer):

(On the "old" computer) Make sure Outlook is closed; copy the PST file to its new location on the "new" computer.
(On the "new" computer) In Outlook, add POP account for the existing account to be moved. Outlook will create a new PST file in its preferred location (Documents folder on OneDrive), but this doesn't matter.
Go to Outlook's account settings dialog (File > Account Settings > Account Settings); select the account in the list and click the Change Folder button (near the bottom-left). Another dialog will appear, showing a list of locations; the appropriate entry should already be selected; click the New Outlook Data File... button and select the file from step 1. (This is the step I overlooked in my earlier unsuccessful attempts).
Close Outlook; go to the location of the PST file created in step 2 and delete this file.
Re-open Outlook; it will check for the original file (from step 2) and prompt you for it; select your copied file (from step 1).
Send a test message from the new account to itself to confirm that both send and receive are working.
(On the "old" computer) Don't forget to disable the account on the old computer, or at least make sure the account settings will leave a copy on the server indefinitely; for the duration the old computer may still be in use, you won't want its Outlook to "steal" emails.
Repeat for all other PST files to be moved.

What I initially failed to realize is that there are two points in Outlook involved with moving a PST.
